# Reverse Proxy to Outside URL-IIS

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

IIS 8

Windows 2012

ARR and URL Rewrite installed

We host a website on behalf of a vendor on one of our servers with the Specs above. That site currently has 3rd party content created by one of their contractors, which we currently host through a subfolder/virtual folder. The contractors now want to host this content securely, but want to use a reverse proxy with a token to do so. Basically they're looking for a rewrite from a link on our page to go to their content, but obviously looking to mask the destination URL.

I've been trying to set this up, and I'm having some trouble with this, as it almost seems like to me that the reverse proxy should be placed on their end, not mine, but I'm more familiar with using a standard forward proxy. I've tried a few different methods, but I just seem to run into more errors than solutions.

ourhostedURL.com (externally accessible)-->Link-->3rdPartyurl.com (with token)

Any help you can provide would be welcome. I've been struggling with this for a bit.

Comment: ARR/URL Rewrite rules perform transformation on HTTP requests from the browsers to the upstream, so first you need to identify clearly what are the incoming requests are, and what the ongoing ones look like. Without that you won't be able to write the correct rules.

Comment: Thanks, but that's still kind of vague. Incoming requests would be from our site via a link to their site passing a token along, and then still showing our URL in the browser.

Comment: When you can use a lot of tools to see into the HTTP packets, such as https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules you won't find my words any vague. Going that deep can save you from struggling.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The one thing it's not doing at the moment is rewriting the URL correctly on outbound (it's still showing the external URL with the token listed and not our URL). In request tracing, it shows that the end URL is going to our URL path, but doesn't show that in the browser.